# Github Update Repository

Tags: git

So I had a repository `X` which I initialized using `GIT init` and then committed several changes into it for a while.

Few months back, I removed my GIT folder from the directory (completely deleted it) for some reason. (i.e hidden git folder inside my root folder).

Today, I did some tweaks and wanted to update those changes into my repo but since that git folder doesn't exist, I again initialized through git commit and created a new repo.

Now, I want to update the repo on github I used previously for X with this new repo. Is there a way I can do it?

I tried going through github for solution but was unable to find anything helpful

Comment: https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Getting-a-Git-Repository

Comment: @choroba Thanks for pointing out. That could've been autocorrect or genuine mistake from my end but isn't the best way to point it out is by making an edit instead of comment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just clone the repository you originally created to get the git folder back.

CD to the location you want to clone the original.

Use

```
 git clone https://github.com/xxxxx.git
```

replacing xxx with your repo

Then move the files from your new project into where you just cloned after you delete the old ones. By cloning the old one to a location you will get your .git files you wanted.

Comment: Haha. That is a smart hack

Answer (score 2):

You can add th remote repo at github with `git remote add` and then do a `git merge --allow-unrelated-histories` if you really want to merge.

If you only made small changes (one or few commits) it will probably better to clone the github repo to a clean directory and then manually merge you changes to that new clone and commit the files again and push all your changes. That way you history will stay clean.